# cli::array<int> to iterator in c++-cli

Tags: iterator, c++-cli

I have managed class with function:

```
int DoSomething(cli::array<int>^ values) { .. }
```

In DoSomething I must call native function:

```
template <class It>
int Calculate(It beg, It end) {..}
```

Which iterator to use?

Comment: That's not how managed code works.  You can use IEnumerable<> or IList<> on an array.  And the for each keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a pinning pointer to the managed array.  This will fix the array in memory (i.e. make it so the garbage collector can't move it) and then you can treat it as a native array.  Below is a sample using your methods.

Take note, that you need to finish using the array before the pinning pointer goes out of scope--once the pinning pointer goes out of scope, the managed array is no longer pinned, and the garbage collector is free to move the array.

Also, take note that pinning the first element of the array causes the entire managed array to be pinned (in general using a pinning pointer on one part of a managed object causes the entire managed object to be pinned).

```
template <class It> int Calculate(It beg, It end) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (; beg != end; ++beg)
    {
        int i = *beg;
        sum += i;
    }

    return sum;
} 

int DoSomething(cli::array<int>^ values)
{
    int numValues = values->Length;
    pin_ptr<int> pNativeValuesBegin = &values[0];
    int * pBegin = pNativeValuesBegin;
    int * pEnd = pBegin + numValues;
    return Calculate(pBegin, pEnd);
} 

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<int> ^ values = gcnew array<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int sum = DoSomething(values);

    System::Console::WriteLine(sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent and very detailed answer, thank you for effort. Only one thing to add: return Calculate<int*>(pBegin, pEnd);

Comment: You're welcome.  You shouldn't need to specify `<int*>` as the compiler can do template argument deduction to determine the type.  It worked fine without specifying it for me in VS2010.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that either. I have some legacy projects in c++ for VS2005 which are not converted ;(